# Why are there several minutes between steps in my Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've noticed recently that in jenkins, there seem to be periods of several minutes of seemingly doing nothing between build steps that I can't account for. In this screenshot (this is from the Blue Ocean plugin view), there are over 4 minutes between the timestamp at the end of a script (`sh` step) and the `echo` I put right after it:

[image: log showing a 4 minute gap between build steps]

How can I figure out what's going on during these 4 minutes?

Comment: Do you notice these discrepancies with the classic console output? Blue Ocean is known to have these sorts of issues...

Comment: I realized these are actually two specific issues here. The first one is the gap between the `sh` and `echo` steps, which, yes, is present in classic console output. The stage time vs. total step time in the 2nd screenshot is because it was provisioning an ec2 node (i use nodes from `ec2-plugin`), which it seems is part of the stage, but not a step, so I'm not worried about that part anymore. I'll edit that out of the question.

Comment: Try to come up with a minimal repro pipeline code. Jenkins doesn't do a whole lot between the steps. It persists execution nodes to files, so if file creation is slow it might take a while, but can't possibly account for the missing 4 minutes.